# How to get AccessToken

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am building a client and need help getting the access token.

would like to know what needs to be passed in grant_type ? client_assertion ?
Where to get these values from ? as these values are required in Authentication in providing AccessToken

POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: :443
Timestamp: 1212669235
Date: Fri, 12 May 2016 17:21:16 GMT+0000
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&scope=profile-search&client_assertion=<JSON Web Signature (JWS)>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 653
Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2019 14:13:29 GMT
{
"access_token" : "KjdsjEeRFwksjqefindikHAfDKV...",
"token_type" : "bearer"
"expires_in" : 3600
"scope":"profile-search"
}

Answer (score 0):

To get the token for Client Credentials type OAuth mechanism, following parameters are needed:

```
grant_type = client credentials
Access Token URL = <the Auth server URL token end point>
ClientId = <the Id from the auth server where app is registered>
ClientSecret = <value for the secret set>
Scope = <scope as defined for the application>
```

Attaching the screenshot from Postman for a sample application to generate the token for this grant type.

More details for it can be referenced from: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/

Sample for this from Azure AD set up is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response. But  if you see in the question I asked, the target system is expecting request parameters client_assertion which is(JWS). Also, target system mentioned they do not authenticate with Basic Auth...they do Bearer Authorization.

Comment: The client_assertion is the JWT token that will be signed with the certificate that you will provide. You can generate the token either programmatically (https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-java-create-verify) , using Postman ( https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4630964/S1Lr3qtg) or online tool (https://oauth.tools/collection/1638334128507-uDb).

Comment: as client_assertion is JWT token that will be signed with cert.....then my question is how do I get Header and Payload values from ? As these Header and Payload combo is JWT Token and needs to be passed as input parameters to get the Access Token in response. And these values change dynamically